# Dynamic item tree url is very lengthy. SEO rank is degrading

Tags: seo

I have a requirement. My application is generating Articles from the Backend.

1. Import data from 3rd party.
2. Convert the Information into Class.
3. Create Items into Sitecore.
   Now based on the Import, the Item creation tree is dynamic. As the data is coming from Import, there is no predictability about the path.

**Example:**

1. sitecore/content/home/article/health/diabetes/low/prescription/medication/simple-diabetic-precautions
2. sitecore/content/home/article/sport/soccer/national/player/goolkeeper/professional/strength/corners/save-theedges
3. sitecore/content/home/articles/health/insurance/medical-type/cancer/blood/stage-3/intense-care-preparation

the above path is just pseudocode, to avoid violations.
can we do anything in this case to shorten the URL?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Sunil Rana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `alias` in `Sitecore` either at the same time while you are creating `articles` in `Sitecore` or manually create `alias` after all articles are created.

**Programmatically create alias**

If you want to create programmatically then create items inside  `/sitecore/system/Aliases` from this template `/sitecore/templates/System/Alias`

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/create-an-alias.html

**Manually create alias**

Below is the link to create an alias manually:

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/create-an-alias-in-the-content-editor.html